# Add a value from one datatable to another c#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datatables, dataset

My knowledge of databases and so on are weak, and I am quite frustrated with it, so I ask help.

If I want to add a value from one datatable to another while executing on click scenario that adds the new values all in the same time, what should I do?

So here is my scenario, I have a dataset with 3 datatables (for this issue we need only two of them, Business and Users)

Datatable 1 (Business)

- B_ID
- B_Name
- B_Pass

Datatable 2 (Users)

- User_ID
- User_Business
- User_Name
- User_Password
- User_Email
- User_Shortcode
- User_AdminRights
- User_UserRights

, I am executing the following code (my registration form registers business data and user data, implements the data seperatly to the two datatables, it works fine but I have no idea how to insert the "B_ID" to "User_Business") :

```
                cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Business where B_Name ='" + textBox1.Text + "'", cn);
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    dr.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Business with this name already exists!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                else
                {
                    dr.Close();
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Business values(@B_Name, @B_Password)", cn);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("B_Name", textBox1.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("B_Password", textBox2.Text);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Users values(@User_Business, @User_Name, @User_Surname, @User_Email, @User_Password, @User_Shortcode, @User_AdminRights, @User_UserRights)", cn);


                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("User_Business", ???); // <- the question mark indicates where I want to add the value of B_ID which is created after inserting business data

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("User_Name", txt_name.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("User_Surname", txt_surname.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("User_Email", txt_email.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("User_Password", txt_pass.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("User_Shortcode", txt_code.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("User_UserRights", 0);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("User_AdminRights", 1);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    MessageBox.Show("Registration succesfull!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    this.Close();
                }
```

So at the end, I want to add the specific "B_ID" value that generates after data is inserted to Business datatable, to "User_Business" value in the Users datatable.

The code works without "User_Business" fine tho, but I am open to new suggestions, thank you.

Comment: So, you need the new `B_ID` (an auto-incrementing Column) assigned to the new record of Business: `Select @@Identity`. But you didn't specify what kind of database you have there (SQL is a *weak reference*). -- Don't concatenate strings to build a query string (first query). Possibly, avoid `AddWithValue()` and use `Parameters.Add()` instead, specifying the exact data type. -- `INSERT INTO` should be explicit in the Columns that it affects.

Comment: e.g.: `insert into Business output inserted.B_ID values(@B_Name, @B_Password)`

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, I have tested and the value is returned by using ExecuteScalar. Thank you again.